# Decimal conversion of time values

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

What is or can be done to add two cells, that return a time equation?

I deal with multiple time entries and have to enter them in a standard format of 4:45 hours or 4:25 hours. I have a decimal converter set up so it will convert it to 4.50, etc.

What I need is a formula that, with the `4` in one cell and the `45` in another, will feed a third cell with the number `4:45` which in turn can feed the fourth cell which is my decimal converter.

I would like it to work like http://www.springfrog.com/converter/decimal-time.htm .
That way I can just input the two separate numbers and get my converted total.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the time() function. e.g:

A1= hour
B1 = minutes
in C1, try:

```
=TIME(A1, B1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

More like the given example (ie including seconds) and assuming hours are in A1, minutes in A2 and seconds in A3:

```
=A1+(A2+A3/60)/60
```

avoids the need for the "decimal converter".

Alternatively, if the data is being entered as `4:25` before being separated manually, skip the separation and apply:

```
 =HOUR(A1)+minute(A1)/60
```

(ignores seconds).

[HOUR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093045)
[MINUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093048)